# Passing true/false variable to function php

Tags: php, function, arguments

Trying to wrap my head around this

```
function any_name($div,$width = false){

   if($width){

      $add_style =' style="width:1000px;"';

   }else{
      $add_style ='';
    }

   html ='<div id="'.$div.'"'.$add_style.'>';
   html .= "</div>';

}




any_name('div1');// should print <div id="div1"></div>
any_name('div2',$width = true);// should print <div id="div2" style="width:1000px;"></div>
```

second function call prints

```
1
<div id="div2"></div>
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Any help is appreciated thank you!

**! fund the real issue** , my function has 2 more arguments 
**function ( $div,arg2,arg3,$width)  the $width was in wrong place thus was resulting in 1**

sorry for the confusion

Comment: Its ok, printing true/false would produce output of 1 or nothing.

Comment: yes but i need it to print div with style attributes . how would I do that ?

Comment: print is reserved function name, its like echo.

Comment: print is just used as example name

Comment: @Benn bad example name to use

Comment: Your code still has typos and parse errors. Are you sure you've posted the exact same thing that you're using?

Comment: Also, do you have to echo from the func or `return` value?

Comment: A good hint is if you are typing code (ever) and it colours the syntax for you and suddenly the whole page turns into red (or whatever colour) text (like the bottom part of your code) then it usually means a quote is missing (or got added accidentally) and warrants further investigation.

Comment: And how come your code is printing something when there is no echo or print statement? -1. If it were possible I'd also give you -1 for every person you confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function any_name($div, $width = false) {

    if ($width) {
        $add_style =' style="width:1000px;"';
    }
    else {
        $add_style ='';
    }

   $html ='<div id="'.$div.'"'.$add_style.'>';
   $html .= '</div>';
   return $html;

}

echo any_name('div1');// should print <div id="div1"></div>
echo any_name('div2', true);// should print <div id="div2" style="width:1000px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

In both the function calls, `$width` is false. If you need to send `true` the 2nd time, you have to do this,

```
 any_name('div1');
 any_name('div2', true);
```

Also, the line `html .= "</div>';` needs to be `html .= "</div>";`, you're missing the closing quotes `"`

Comment: just wrote fast ,  closing is in place in my file , thnx !

Comment: I don't agree, $width would **should** still evaluate to true even if you use `any_function($variable = true);`. It doesn't make any sense to do it that way, but it would 'work'.  See also: http://codepad.viper-7.com/CY1GBx

Comment: @terry that is what I thought it would be , but it is not

Comment: yes terry you are right , I edited my question and posted the real issue , I had 2 more arguments and width was in wrong place

Comment: @TerrySeidler Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: This is why you should try to post the real code, rather than "example code that looks like the real code but actually isn't" ;-)